# Get dropdown attribute text - Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to retrieve the text value for the manufacturer attribute. It is a dropdown field. I tried this:

```
$manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
$manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();
```

`$manufacturerName` should display "*BrandName*", but it always displays **1** even if I change the manufacturer. The `$manufacturerId` changes when I change the manufacturer.

I don't understand why the manufacturer name is not displayed correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can check on this code:

```
$manufacturerName  = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
$manufacturerId  = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62220/getattributetext-use-default-value-regardless-what-store-view-the-user-is-on

Answer (score 5):

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product->getAttributeText('attributeCode');
```

Worked for me.